# Rate of decay problem for chemical reaction

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve this problem but my answer isn't the same as in the book:

> In a certain chemical reaction the rate of conversion of a substance
>   is proportional to the amount of the substance still untransformed at
>   that time. After $10$ min one-third of the original amount of the
>   substance has been converted, and $20$g has been converted after $15$ min.
>   What was the original amount of the substance.

So, I have:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
t(s) &\quad& A(g) \\
0 && A_0 \\
10 && \frac{A_0}{3} \\
15 && 20
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I then use

$$
\frac{\textrm{d}A}{\textrm{d}t} = kA \\
\frac{\textrm{d}A}{A} = k\textrm{d}t
$$

After I integrate both sides, I have

$$
A = Ce^{kt}
$$

At $t = 0$

$$
A_0 = Ce^{0k} \\
A_0 = C
$$

At $t = 10$, using $C = A_0$

$$
\frac{A_0}{3} = A_0e^{10k} \\
k = \frac{ln\frac{1}{3}}{10}
$$

At $t = 15$, using $C = A_0$ and $k = \frac{ln\frac{1}{3}}{10}$

$$
20 = A_0e^{15\frac{ln\frac{1}{3}}{10}} \\
A_0 = \frac{20}{e^{15\frac{ln\frac{1}{3}}{10}}} \\
A_0 \approx 104 \textrm{g}
$$

The answer in the book is $43.9$g but I really don't see my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One third has been converted means that $\frac{2}{3}$ remain, i.e. you should have $\frac{2}{3}A_0$ instead of $\frac{A_0}{3}$. Similarly, after $15$ mn you have still $A_0-20$, not $20.$ (Since $20$g is what has been converted.)

This will lead first to $k = \frac{1}{10}\ln\frac{2}{3}$, and then $20 -A_0 = A_0 e^{-\frac{3}{2}\ln\frac{3}{2}}$. Solving this [yields](http://tinyurl.com/hkbq7u6) $A_0= \frac{20}{1-e^{-\frac{3}{2}\ln\frac{3}{2}}}\simeq 43.89$.

Comment: Brilliant, I tried your suggestion on my side too and I get the right answer plus I understand this type of problem much better now. Thanks!